# Sum of consecutive terms of expansion $(x+y)^n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, taylor-expansion

Let $S(x, y, m_1,m_2, n) = \sum\limits_{i=m_1}^{m_2} \binom{n}{i}x^i y^{n-i}$, where $0 < m_1\leq m_2 < n$. I want to derive the relation between $S(x, y, m_1, m_2, n)$ and $S(x, y, m_1-1, m_2, n-1)$.

Is there any formulas I can use? Similarly to the [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414224/sum-of-the-first-m-terms-of-the-expansion-xyn) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with: $$S(x,y,m_1,m_2,n)=xS(x,y,m_1-1,m_2-1,n-1)+yS(x,y,m_1,m_2,n-1)$$

Then use:$$S(x,y,m_1-1,m_2-1,n-1)= S(x,y,m_1-1,m_2,n-1)-\binom {n-1}{m_2}x^{m_2}y^{n-1-m_2}\\
S(x,y,m_1,m_2,n-1)= S(x,y,m_1-1,m_2,n-1)-\binom {n-1}{m_1-1}x^{m_1-1}y^{n-m_1} $$

You get: $$\begin{align}S(x,y,m_1,m_2,n)&=(x+y)S(x,y,m_1-1,m_2,n-1)\\&\quad-\binom {n-1}{m_2}x^{m_2+1}y^{n-(m_2+1)}-\binom {n-1}{m_1-1}x^{m_1-1}y^{n-(m_1-1)}\end{align}$$

That agrees with the formula in your link when $m_1=0, m_2=m.$

---

You can get this formula directly from the link if you realize the relation (I’ll use $S_0$ for the $S$ in the link):

$$S(x,y,m_1,m_2,n)=S_0(x,y,m_2,n)-S_0(x,y,m_1-1,n)$$